# Pure CSS Slider not functioning as desired

Tags: html, css, slider

I would like to implement a pure CSS slider which has the following components :-

- Automatic Slideshow
- Navigation buttons to move left and right
- Indicator buttons to show which image is currently displayed

I had these modules implemented in 2 separate codes but when i combined them, only the first image displays and then the remaining images become invisible. I cant figure out what is going wrong.

This is the HTML code:

```
    <body>

<ul class="slides">

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img class="image" src="img/1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img class="image" src="img/2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img class="image" src="img/3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img class="image" src="img/4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>

    </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

And here is the corresponding CSS Code that i have done till now:

```
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 550px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 550px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.35; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: -5px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.slide, .nav-dot {
    opacity:0;

    /* css3 animation */
    -webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -moz-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* delays */
.slide, .nav-dot:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
.slide, .nav-dot:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;
}
.slide, .nav-dot:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18.0s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    10% {opacity:1;}
    30% {opacity:1;}
    36% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {
     0% {opacity:0;}
    10% {opacity:1;}
    30% {opacity:1;}
    36% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/8njq14v1/)..this is what your code is..i think this is working correctly...

Comment: It works in a haphazard manner. That's the problem. The images become permanently invisible and don't appear properly as a slide show, which is the intended use.